# Prolog return duplicate list

Tags: list, prolog

I am getting duplicated list when I try to findall/3 possible path in a graph? Any idea what is wrong with the code? The pattern of duplicate was S:6 was duplicated with S:13, S:7 with S:14, S:8 with S:15 and so on..

```
 co(X,Y) :- hen(X,Y) ; hen(Y,X).

 pan(A, B, _, [A,B]) :- co(A, B).
 pan(A, B, Vix, [A | Len]) :-
     co(A, C),
     C \== B,
     \+ member(C, Vix),
     pan(C, B, [C | Vix], Len).

 long_p(A, B):-
     findall(Len, pan(A,B,[A],Len), Z),
     printT(Z,0).

 printT([],_).
 printT([H|T],V) :-
     V1 is V + 1,
     write('S: '), write(V1), nl,
     write(H), nl,
     nl,
     printT(T,V1).
```

Will Prolog findall/3 return a distinct result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna guess.

`printT/2` prints the `S:(length-of-path)`. Why shouldn't there be multiple paths from A to B with the same length?

I guess your problem is that `long_p/2` succeeds twice for the same path. I don't see any reason for this in `pan/4`. Unless I'm wrong with that, the reason is in `co/2` and/or `hen/2`. For example, if you have `hen(a,b)` and `hen(b,a)` in your database, `co(a,b)` will succeed twice. This could be fixed with

```
co(X,Y) :- hen(X,Y).
co(X,Y) :- hen(Y,X), \+ hen(X,Y).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
findall(Len, pan(A,B,[A],Len), Z)
```

will produce the list `Z` with **all** `Len`'s , such that `pan(A,B,[A],Len)` succeeds. So, `pan(A,B,[A],Len)` is backtracked and all solutions `Len` are put into the list `Z`.

In your graph there is a route of length 6 between two specific nodes `A` and `B`. But there is also a path from `A` to `B` via some `C` with the length 13. `findall` finds these two routes, etc.